# GoogleMaps on Android using Google API 2.3.3 Level 10, finding by address

Tags: android, google-maps, dictionary, geocoding

Im trying to display the address from an EditText using geoCoder and also it would be able editable to click on the finder button and update the googlemap display on the top of the screen, this is my code:

```
Geocoder geocoder = null;
MapView mapView = null;
int lat, lng;
EditText loc;

@Override
protected boolean isRouteDisplayed() {
    return false;
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {

    super.onCreate(icicle);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    mapView = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.geoMap);

    try 
    {
        loc = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.location);
        String locationName = loc.getText().toString();
        List<Address> addressList = geocoder.getFromLocationName(locationName, 5);

        if (addressList != null && addressList.size() > 0) {
            lat = (int) addressList.get(0).getLatitude() * 1000000;
            lng = (int) addressList.get(0).getLongitude() * 1000000;
            GeoPoint pt = new GeoPoint(lat, lng);
            mapView.getController().setZoom(10);
            mapView.getController().setCenter(pt);
            mapView.getController().animateTo(pt);
        }
    } 
    catch 
    (IOException e) 
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }



    //
    Button geoBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.geocodeBtn);
    geocoder = new Geocoder(this);
    //
    geoBtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            try {
                EditText loc = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.location);
                String locationName = loc.getText().toString();
                List<Address> addressList = geocoder.getFromLocationName(locationName, 5);

                if (addressList != null && addressList.size() > 0) {
                    int lat = (int) addressList.get(0).getLatitude() * 1000000;
                    int lng = (int) addressList.get(0).getLongitude() * 1000000;
                    GeoPoint pt = new GeoPoint(lat, lng);
                    mapView.getController().setZoom(10);
                    mapView.getController().setCenter(pt);
                    mapView.getController().animateTo(pt);
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
}
```

But it crashes at this point: List addressList = geocoder.getFromLocationName(locationName, 5);
Im using googles APi 2.3.3.

Comment: Stack trace? Possibly `locationName` is `null` or service unavailable?

Comment: Can you paste the exact stack trace in an edit to your answer? I think it's a network exception but can't confirm it without the stack trace.

Comment: Sorry it was a service unavailable error, how can i fix it?

Comment: java.io.IOException: Service not Available

Comment: at android.location.Geocoder.getFromLocationName(GeoCoder.java.178)

Comment: Are you using the emulator and are you compiling against the Google Add-ons API for 2.3.3?